# sum of two number using def function in python

Tags: python, function

feed function using `raw_input` of `sys.argv` for sum of two number goes just showing in list

```
def sum_double(a, b):
    sum = a+b
    if a == b:
            sum = sum*2
            print sum
            return sum
    else :
            print sum
            return  sum
sum_double(a = raw_input("a"),b = raw_input("b"))
```

[image]

if we feed input are 1 and 2 then it will showing 12 instead of 3

Comment: So your basically looking to concatenate Strings, correct?

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots of text. Post the text itself, in a code block to preserve formatting.

Comment: I think you need to tell us why you want to use a function to do this...

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a *string* and not a number. With string inputs, `+` simply concatenates the two strings together.

```
'1' + '2'
# '12'
```

If you want to perform numeric operations (such as addition), you need to first convert the output of `raw_input` to a number using `int` (for integers) or `float` (for floating point numbers).

```
sum_double(a = int(raw_input("a")),b = int(raw_input("b")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a string ('1' and '2'). Summing them gives you '12'.

In order to sum numbers, not strings, convert the strings to numbers:

```
sum_double(a = int(raw_input("a")),b = int(raw_input("b")))
```